# ajax url append on current url on document ready and giving 302 error

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

current href is "http://127.0.0.1:8000/report-page/34"
In back it should be /sort-list but it is appending after "/report-page" like "GET /report-page/sort-list HTTP/1.1" 302 0
Actually for some reason on previous request I have send id on url and I need that.

In js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
     url: "sort-list",
     type: "GET",
     headers: { "X-CSRFToken": $.cookie("csrftoken") },
     success: function(response){
      };
   });
});
```

I'm using ajax call on doc ready

Comment: If you want http://127.0.0.1:8000/sort-list then in your document.ready() function, change the url from "sort-list" to "/sort-list"

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need a CSRF token for a GET request.

Comment: Thanks @Nalin Dobhal it worked

Answer (score 1):

Better You can use like below statement

```
var your_url = "/sort-list" ; // /sort-list for http://127.0.0.1:8000/sort-list
var your_url = "sort-list" ; // sort-list for http://127.0.0.1:8000/report-page/34/sort-list

 $.ajax({url: your_url , success: function(result){
    $("#yourelement").html(result);
  }});
```